# Google Sheets api Append and Change Colour of the row (Node js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have been  trying format sheets row while appending, but can't figure it out.
I have no problem with appending the rows, it works fine. So how can I append and format the row  simultaneously ? From what I know I should be using "batchUpdate()" function,  I tried in many ways but  still  can't figure it out.

Comment: Can you please share what you tried so far, including the code you currently have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to append a row to a sheet in a Google Spreadsheet.
- When the row is appended, you want to set the color (background color?) to the row.
- You want to achieve this using Node.js.

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

In this script, googleapis for Node.js is used. [Ref](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client) This can be used with Quickstart. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/nodejs)

```js
const sheets = google.sheets({ version: "v4", auth }); // Please use your authorization script.

const spreadsheetId = "###"; // Please set your Spreadsheet ID.
const sheetId = "0"; // Please set your sheet ID.
const appendValue = ["sample1", "sample2", "sample3"]; // This is a sample append value.
const backgroundColor = { red: 1, green: 0, blue: 0 }; // This is a sample background color. In this case, the red color is used.

const values = appendValue.map((e) => ({userEnteredValue: { stringValue: e }, userEnteredFormat: { backgroundColor }}));
const requests = [{appendCells: {rows: [{ values }], sheetId, fields: "userEnteredValue,userEnteredFormat"}}];
await sheets.spreadsheets.batchUpdate({spreadsheetId, resource: { requests }});
```

- When this script is run, a row of `"sample1", "sample2", "sample3"` is appended to the sheet, and the background color of the cells of the appended row is set as the red color.

#### Note:

- This is a simple sample script. So, please modify this for your actual situation.

#### References:

- [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)
- [AppendCellsRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#appendcellsrequest)